# Undo a deleted cell in databricks notebook?

Tags: databricks

Is there any way to restore a command cell in databricks notebook when we delete it? I don't see any commend in databricks to undo a deleted cell. The databricks version is v2.99.
[image]

[image]

**Edit:** At the time of writing this question "UNDO DELETE" was not available in Databricks.

Answer (score 9):

Try going to `Revision History` in the top right hand corner of the notebook.

This should give you a drop down with the history of the notebook, including auto-save points.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Or you can go `Edit` and then `Undo Delete Cells`

[image]

Comment: This should be the top answer, it might be a newer functionality

Comment: This option was not available at the time of writing the question.